# Duplicate Column error while creating a view

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to create a view for the following code:

```
       (SELECT* FROM v1) view1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN salesperson sp
    on sp.salespersonid = view1.salespersonid;
```

This result gives me the exact amount of records I need and provides the correct information, but when i do the following

```
      CREATE VIEW v2 AS 
      SELECT * FROM 
         (SELECT* FROM v1) view1
         LEFT OUTER JOIN salesperson sp
        on sp.salespersonid = view1.salespersonid;
```

I get the following error

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
CREATE VIEW v2
AS 
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT*
  FROM v1) view1
LEFT OUTER JOIN salesperson sp
on sp.salespersonid = view1.salespersonid
Error report -
ORA-00957: duplicate column name
00957. 00000 -  "duplicate column name"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't the error obvious?  The view cannot have duplicate column names.  When creating the view, you should really list all the columns explicitly.

But, if the only duplicated column is `salespersonid`, you can use this shortcut:

```
CREATE VIEW v2 AS 
    SELECT *
    FROM v1 view1 LEFT JOIN
         salesperson sp
         USING (salespersonid);
```

Comment: I appreciate the quick response! I knew that the error was from the duplicate column but I wasn't exactly sure how to fix it as I'm a student currently learning SQL and they did not go over fixing this kind of error in class. I was just told to do a left outer join with the table. If it's not too bothersome how else could I solve this?

Comment: @Allysoncv . . . The right solution is to list all the columns explicitly.